# Populating a Combo Box with DisplayField-ValueField Items Similar to like we do in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a combo Item that I want to populate with a list of objects, similar to "ListItem" Class found in asp.net. Is there a build object for Windows forms that has similar behavior? What I do now is create an utility class that has two properties, ValueField and DisplayField, and then create a generic list from this class and give this list as a datasource to the Combo box, is there a better approach?

PS: We just started using VS 2010

Regards

Answer (score 4):

You can simply set your object collection as `DataSource` of `ComboBox`. Then set the `DisplayMember` property of `ComboBox` equal to `Property` which you want `ComboBox` to display.

Similarly for value field you can use `ValueMember` property of `ComboBox`

A Utility class only for this purpose would be overkill I guess

Comment: First Thank you, Second could you please send a simple example?

Comment: @odiseh: I think my answer is pretty self explanatory. Google for examples. Code will be like this `ComboBox combo = new ComboBox();
            List<SomeClass> obj = new List<SomeClass>();
            combo.DisplayMember = "Some Property";
            combo.ValueMember = "Some Property";
            combo.DataSource = obj; `

Comment: Thanks Haris, but the problem is that I don't have the SomeClass. In asp.net there is a build in class that makes it easier. What I actual have is a HashTable that is coming from some external library, I need to give this hash table as a source to a combo box, and combo boxes don't accept complex types such as hash tables. So Thats why i need a container class to fill the values, Thanks :)

Comment: May be I don't understand you 100%. As far as I know ComboBox accept a Hashtable as datasource. Also you can set HastTable.Value as datasource

Comment: Setting the hash table as a data source directly gives the error: "Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource." the hashtable is like this  SortedList<object, string> arrDomains ; even when using the Values property it is giving the same thing :S